# Fadeout element and slide in the rest in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid of images loaded on a page. They are essentially `div`'s  next to each other and when the page fills up it moves to the next row.

When I click on an image I want that image to fadeout and once the animation is complete, I want the rest of the elements to slide in to fill up its spot.

I have no problem with the clicking and fading, just the sliding of the remaining elements. Currently they just jump to fill up its spot as soon as the animation is complete.

EDIT:
Forgot the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/YuFqh/

Comment: Have you tried to use the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function in some form? You may be forced to animate the height of the element to 0 before actually hiding the image.

Comment: I looked into it, but i'm not quite sure how to implement it and @TusharGupta sorry, I forgot to include it! My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".profileImage").click(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity: "0.0"}).animate({width: 0}).hide(0);
})
```

Animate your opacity to 0 to fade it from view, then animate your width to 0 to regain the space, then hide it to remove it from visibility altogether. Note that if you want to redisplay, you'll have to restore the previous values.

http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/YuFqh/2/

Answer (score 1):

what about using the fadeOut callback

```
$(".profileImage").click(function() {

     $(this).animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
          // sliding code goes here
          $(this).animate({width:0},300).hide();
     });

});
```